# URL redirect and spammers

Tags: redirect, spam

I have a couple of sites that are being attacked (for the last 4 months), about 50k requests from about 3k unique visitors a day. The format of the url from the referrer is:
domain.org.uk/?URL=google.com.iq for example.
I have the sites on Cloudflare to reduce the bandwidth drain but am wondering if there is something I can do to prevent the URL redirect feature of Craft from responding to this format of URL or respond in a better way?
I'm looking at adding this to the htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 403 default
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} URL
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F,L]
```

But wonder if there is something better?
I'm concerned that the sites will get blacklisted as a source of spam.

Comment: Apache ``mod_security`` or ``mod_evasive`` can help with this.  There's no equivalent to this in Apache but in nginx you can send an internal 444 response which just drops the connection and can be handy if you know the referrer is junk.